# Python string split in a specific pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split a string in this specific pattern:

```
'ff19shh24c' -> ['f', 'f', '19s', 'h', 'h', '24c']
```

I managed to get this close:

```
import re

string = "ff19shh24c"

parts = re.findall(r'\D+|\d+[a-z]{1}')

print(parts) -> ['ff', '19s', 'hh', '24c']
```

But now I am a little bit stuck.

Comment: Can you explain the logic? There are many possible interpretations

Comment: do you want not regex solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for anything (non-greedy) and then a letter.

```
import re

string = "ff19shh24c"
parts = re.findall(r'.*?[a-z]', string)
print(parts)
```

This will give you `['f', 'f', '19s', 'h', 'h', '24c']`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, find zero or more digits, then a non-digit:

```
import re

string = 'ff19shh24c'
parts = re.findall('\d*\D', string)
```

output: `['f', 'f', '19s', 'h', 'h', '24c']`

Answer (score 0):

Since question not tagged with `regex` or similar here a for loop approach

```
s = 'ff19shh24c'

out = []
tmp = ''
was_a_digit = False # keep track if the previous character was a digit
for char in s:
    if char.isdigit():
        was_a_digit = True
        tmp += char
    else:
        if was_a_digit:
            tmp += char
            out.append(tmp)
            tmp = ''
            was_a_digit = False
        else:
            out.append(char)

print(out)
#['f', 'f', '19s', 'h', 'h', '24c']
```

---

In case of strings which end with digits the above code will loose these characters but with a slight edit one can still retrieve them.

Here the approach with *conservation of characters*:

```
s = 'ff19shh24cX29ZZ88'

... same as above

# directly after the end of the for loop
out.append(tmp)

print(out)
['f', 'f', '19s', 'h', 'h', '24c', 'X', '29Z', 'Z', '88']
```